# Spring boot Swagger 3 - Controller summary is not getting displayed by default in OpenApi documentation

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

By default, the API method name is displayed as a summary in  [Swagger2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b22Va.png)

But, is not displayed in [OpenApi3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMfuI.png) by default.

How can I configure this property? Without using `@Operation(summary = "Summary")` in each controller endpoint.

Dependency: `implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-ui', version: '1.5.10'`

Comment: When you say Swagger2, do you mean the OpenAPI specification version is 2.x or the 3.x?

Comment: @DebarghaRoy Thanks, for the comment. 

swagger 2: io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2

openApi 3:  org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method name in OpenAPI v3 is represented by the [`operationId`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/) field.

Springdoc by default doesn't show the `operationId`. To enable it, you'll need to set the below property to `true` in your application's property file (for instance, `application.properties`, `application.yml` etc.)

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.displayOperationId=true
```

Although the `operationId` can be specified explicitly like so

```java
@Operation(summary = "Some method", operationId = "Operation 1", description = "Some Description")
```

which gives you the output as below
[image: custom-operation-id]

But if you don't specify the `operationId` field explicitly, it defaults to the method name (which is your desired output).

Consider the below code sample

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/create/{userId}", consumes = {MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, IMAGE_PNG_VALUE, IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, MULTIPART_MIXED_VALUE}, produces = {TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE})
@Operation(summary = "Save File", description = "Save the file to the disk")
public ResponseEntity<Object> saveFile(
    @Parameter(description = "ID of the user") 
    @PathVariable(value = "userId") final String userId,
) {
    return null;
}

@GetMapping(value = "/get", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "OK", content = {@Content(schema = @Schema(type = "string", format = "binary"))})
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getFile() {
    return null;
}
```

The above code fragment will give the below output

[image: implicity-operation-id]

Answer (score 1):

To see more details for each endpoint in the swagger-ui such as metadata, comments, and descriptions in the openapi3 yaml spec file; you can include javadoc by adding the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-javadoc</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then add the plugin below:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>com.github.therapi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>therapi-runtime-javadoc-scribe</artifactId>
                        <version>0.15.0</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

See https://springdoc.org/#javadoc-support